# (Typescript) Can you validate all possible properties in a partial return type are being optionally mapped onto a new object at compile time?

Tags: typescript, validation, types, mapping

G'day everyone - I have a service that is made up of a database reader, some transformations in the middle, and a "sync" service that posts requests to a third party API.

The types look like:

```
export interface RowType {
  userId: string,
  userSeq: number,
  info: InfoType
}

export type InfoType = Partial<{
  propertyA: number,
  propertyB: boolean,
  propertyC: string,
  propertyD: boolean,
}>;
```

The reader looks like:

```
export const usePostgresReader = (
  pool: Pool,
  tenant: string,
  limit = 1000,
): PersistedReader<RowType> => ({
  head: async () =>
    pool
      .query(
        `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(position), 0) as head 
        FROM table_name`,
      )
      .then(({ rows }) => Number(rows[0].head)),
  read: async from =>
    pool
      .query(
        `SELECT position, user_id, user_seq, payload
        FROM table_name
        WHERE tenant = $1 AND position > $2
        ORDER BY position ASC
        LIMIT $3`,
        [tenant, from, limit],
      )
      .then(({ rows }) =>
        rows.map<Persisted<RowType>>(
          ({ position, user_id: userId, user_seq: userSeq, payload }) => ({
            position: Number(position),
            payload: {
              customerId,
              customerSequence: Number(customerSequence),
              info: {
                propertyA: info.propertyA,
                propertyB: info.propertyB,
                propertyC: info.propertyC
                // should be propertyD: info.propertyD, but the dev forgets to add it
              },
            },
          }),
        ),
      ),
});
```

The "sync" service looks like this:

```
export const useSyncService = (
  getToken: AuthService,
): SyncService => async rows =>
  fetch(`https://some-other-site.com/api`, {
    method: `POST`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${await getToken()}`,
      'Content-Type': `application/json`,
    },
    timeout: 60000,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      input: rows.map(({ userId, info }) => ({
        apiThingA: info.propertyA,
        apiThingB: info.propertyB,
        apiThingC: info.propertyC,
        apiThingD: info.propertyD // compiler is happy with this because of partial type
      })),
    }),
  })
```

Engineers working on this code are constantly adding new fields to the sync payload, and we have stumbled on this a few times now - we are adding the new field to the body of the request, but not to the reader return type.

HOWEVER, because the row type is a partial (and has to be, as many services populate the table it is reading from all with different payloads), the compiler does not complain about a value being mapped from a type where is is allowed to be undefined, even though if you forget to add it to the reader it will ALWAYS be undefined.

Is there a way to catch this at compile time? I am trying to figure out how to use a library like Zod (https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) to validate this stuff but my current solutions will only catch it at run-time.

Cheers in advance, legends!

Answer (score 1):

The compile-time solution for this that I have figured out is to redeclare the partial type as a union type.

ie. instead of:

```
export type InfoType = Partial<{...}>
```

... I declare every possible payload shape explicitly and declare the `InfoType` as a union of all of them.

Such as:

```
type InfoTypeA = {...}
type InfoTypeB = {...}
type InfoTypeC = {...}
type InfoTypeD = {...}

export type InfoType = InfoTypeA | InfoTypeB | InfoTypeC | InfoTypeD
```

This way, an request body (`{}`) won't be valid anymore, so a type error will be thrown if the compiler finds a scenario where it can't map the available values to a valid sub-type of the union.

Hope this helps anyone else that runs into a similar problem!